# Understanding why I need to dispatch back to main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading

I just wanted to clear up something that feels a bit unclear for me. Consider the following code that executes a closure asynchronously:

```
func fetchImage(completion: UIImage? -> ()) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    // fetch the image data over the internet

    // ... assume I got the data
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      completion(image)
    }
  }
}
```

To my understanding, the reason we need to dispatch back to the main thread is because it would otherwise take longer to call the completion closure to give back the image.

However, I feel that perspective is a bit cheesy. For example, I'd also like to create a `isLoading` property that would be used to prevent multiple network calls from happening at the same time:

```
func fetchImage(completion: UIImage? -> ()) {
  // if isLoading is true, then don't continue getting the image because I want only 1 network operation to be running at 1 time.
  if isLoading { 
    completion(nil)
    return 
  }

  isLoading = true
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    let image = UIImage(data: data)

    // image creation is complete. Set isLoading to false to allow new fetches
    self.isLoading = false
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      completion(image)
    }
  }
}
```

For this above snippet, my question is - Should I place `self.isLoading = false` in the dispatch block to the main queue? Or is it insignificant?

All advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that "it would otherwise take longer", it is that all updates to the UI **must be performed on the main queue** to prevent corruption that may occur from concurrent updates to the autolayout environment or other UI datastructures that aren't thread-safe.

In prior versions of iOS a common side effect of *not* updating the UI on the main thread was a delay in that upgrade appearing, however as of iOS 9 you will get an exception.

In terms of your question, it is best that your code behaves consistently. I.e. Either *always* dispatch the completion handler on the main queue or *never* do so. This will allow the programmer who is writing the completion block to know whether they need to dispatch UI updates or not.

It is probably best to set `isLoading` to false as soon as the load has finished, so outside the `dispatch_async` is best.

Given that your function is retrieving a `UIImage` there is a good chance that the caller will be updating the UI, so it is probably 'nice' to dispatch the completion handler on the main thread.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate the `isLoading` part? Outside the `dispatch_async` that dispatches to the main thread or dispatches to the background thread?

Comment: The dispatch onto the main queue; ie where it is now. If you it do it earlier it will be cleared before the load has finished.

Comment: And as per the other answer, if you are retrieving the image from the network, most network operations are already asynchronous, so you probably don't need the background dispatch.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the image from internet in background you simply need to do an async request, you don't need to do it in the background queue as you are doing now.

On the main thread you basically need to do all that things about UI manipulation, because it always run on main thread. This is the important part.

So, the request completion block (the one you'll use to fetch the image) is executed in background (since it is async) and here, inside the block, you need to get the main thread to set the image for the UIImageView for instance.
Other properties than the ones directly related to UI element doesn't needs to be on the main thread as far as I know and I have never had a problem this way.